# Trouble with Sequential Search

Tags: java, search, sequential

Basically I need to perform a **Sequential Search** through list of items for the word either *Category* or *Dietary* and produce the list of items information in the following output format:

**Data Format:**

```
ID|Name|Description|Category|Dietary|Quantity|Unit Price
```

**Output:**

```
Please enter the number:
1 to search category
2 to search dietary
3 to display all records
4 to insert record
5 to remove old records 
or enter '6' to quit.

1

Please enter the number:
1 to search category
2 to search dietary
3 to display all records
4 to insert record
5 to remove old records 
or enter '6' to quit.

rice
1004|Premium Fragrant Rice|Large Size|Rice|Organic|2|9.5

Please enter the number:
1 to search category
2 to search dietary
3 to display all records
4 to insert record
5 to remove old records 
or enter '6' to quit.
```

But my problem is when I run my program, I input 1 on the user menu to search for category then it never display the list of items information. But I'm not sure how to fix the code on Line 81?

**My Output:**

```
    Please enter the number:
    1 to search category
    2 to search dietary
    3 to display all records
    4 to insert record
    5 to remove old records 
    or enter '6' to quit.

    1

    Please enter the number:
    1 to search category
    2 to search dietary
    3 to display all records
    4 to insert record
    5 to remove old records 
    or enter '6' to quit.

    rice

    Please enter the number:
    1 to search category
    2 to search dietary
    3 to display all records
    4 to insert record
    5 to remove old records 
    or enter '6' to quit.
```

**Java:**

```
String INPUT_PROMPT = "\nPlease enter the number:\n" + 
                "1 to search category"
                + "\n2 to search dietary" + "\n3 to display all records" + "\n4 to insert record" + "\n5 to remove old records " + "\nor enter '6' to quit." +"\n";
        System.out.println(INPUT_PROMPT);

        try
        {        
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                    (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
            line = reader.readLine();


            while(!line.equals("6"))
            {    
                switch(line)
                {
                    //Search word for Category
                    case "1": <-----Line 81
                    int i=0; 
                    while(i<prdct.size())
                    {
                        if(prdct.get(i).category.contains(line))
                        {
                             System.out.println(prdct.get(i));
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    if(i == 0)
                    {   
                        System.out.println("Record not found");
                    }
                    break;

                    case "3":
                    for(int h=0; h<prdct.size(); h++)
                    {
                        System.out.println(prdct.get(h));
                    }
                    break;
                }

                System.out.println(INPUT_PROMPT);
                line = reader.readLine(); 

            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Input Error!");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code below, line by line:

```
line = reader.readLine();
```

You read a line first.

```
while(!line.equals("6"))
{    
    switch(line)
    {
        //Search word for Category
        case "1":
```

Then you check the line you read to see if the user entered "1".

```
        int i=0; 
        while(i<prdct.size())
        {
            if(prdct.get(i).category.contains(line))
```

Then you search the list for the line the user entered.

You never take new user input! So instead of searching for the category the user wants, you are still searching for the string "1".  Take user input again to fix this problem. Just add another `reader.readLine()` before searching the list, like this:

```
        line = reader.readLine();
        int i=0; 
        while(i<prdct.size())
        {
            if(prdct.get(i).category.contains(line))
```